# Do enum values behave like global variables?

Tags: c++, enums

I have two enums, and if there is one value in one enum with the same name as a value in the other enum:

```
enum A {joe, bob, doc};
enum B {sunday, monday, doc};
```

The compiler (Visual Studio's) complains about redefinition of `doc`, which implies it treats it as a global variable. Is this so? It is not the behavior I would expect, and it forces me to manage names of all enum elements in my project.

Any insights would help.

Comment: Could we see more code ? Maybe the issue is something around.

Comment: This is not normal behaviour from the compiler, afaik.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this! And it is the same for C?

Comment: @ykatchou: it happens if the two lines above are the only lines in the cpp file being compiled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enumerators in C++03 have the same scope as the enumeration .

```
enum     xxx    {    yyy,       zzz       };
          ^           ^          ^ 
    enumeration    enumerator enumerator
```

This is sometimes convenient, sometimes not really.

In C++0x we will have `enum class`es which are more like C#'s `enums`. In the meantime, just assume (cause that's the language rule) that `yyy` and `zzz` have exactly the same scope as `xxx`

Answer (score 12):

It's not treated as a global *variable*.  It's treated as a global *identifier*.

More precisely, it's treated as an identifier in whatever namespace the `enum` is declared in.  In your case, that's the global namespace.

For an idea of what the difference is between a global identifier and a global variable, try taking the address of your enum. ;)

Usually when I define enums, I prepend the an abbreviated version of the name of the identifier.  Like this:

```
enum InstrumentType { itStock, itEquityOption, itFutureOption };
```

This helps to avoid collisions.

Comment: I was going to laugh hard if out of all the answers to this question not one had addressed the variable issue.  +1

Comment: I felt that 'variable' is not the right term, but I didn't have any better one (now I have...)

Answer (score 10):

Wyatt Anderson has already suggested

```
namespace A
{
    enum A {joe, bob, doc};
}
namespace B
{
    enum B {sunday, monday, doc};
}
```

as a fix for the "enum values are in the same scope as the enum itself" problem, allowing you to write

```
A::doc;
B::doc;
```

But this solution is not available when you want an `enum` local to a class, at least not without introducing an artificial namespace outside the class.

A simple solution is to instead wrap each `enum` in a struct, like so:

```
struct A
{
    enum Enum {joe, bob, doc};
};
struct B
{
    enum Enum {sunday, monday, doc};
};
```

This allows the same usage notation as with the namespace solution,

```
A::doc;
B::doc;
```

but it additionally allows

- definition within a class,
- bringing the enumeration names directly into a class via inheritance, and
- local-in-class renaming of the qualifier, via `typedef`.

Plus, the *naming convention* exemplified above allows

- in my view, a little extra clarity when referring to an enum type, e.g. writing `A::Enum`.

OK, the naming convention can also be used with the namespace based solution…

Cheers & hth.,

Answer (score 5):

If you want them to be global, fix your problem and avoid namespace pollution by throwing your `enum`s in a namespace:

```
namespace A
{
    enum A {joe, bob, doc};
}
namespace B
{
    enum B {sunday, monday, doc};
}

A::doc;
B::doc;
```

Answer (score 2):

The values of an enumeration exist in whatever scope the `enum` was declared in.

The following works, for example:

```
enum A {joe, bob, doc};
namespace C { enum B {sunday, monday, doc}; }
```

or

```
class A_class { enum A {joe, bob, doc}; };
class B_class { enum B {sunday, monday, doc}; };
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum's values have the scope of the enum itself, that is, it's declaration scope. For example:

```
enum A {value = 30};

int main()
{
   enum B {value = 32};
   int x = value;
}
```

x will be 32.

Comment: Nope, but you'll have 11 errors in your code. Try and compile it

Comment: But if you change `enum 1` to `enum A` and `enum 2` to `enum B` the code will compile and you will still show the scope. Win-Win?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say we want to declare aspect ratio for a graphical window. Then defining the enum values as already suggested:

```
struct __aspect_ratio__
{
    enum values
    {
        ASPECT_RATIO_16_9,  // HD video
        ASPECT_RATIO_16_2,  // *for testing purposes*
        ASPECT_RATIO_4_3,   // standard monitor
        ASPECT_RATIO_3_2,   // classic film
        ASPECT_RATIO_21_9,  // cinemascope
        ASPECT_RATIO_1_1    // quadratic window
    };
};

typedef __aspect_ratio__::values AspectRatio;
```

The `typedef` in the end allows us to use `AspectRatio::ASPECT_RATIO_16_9` as a shorthand for, e.g. function signatures:

```
void SetAspectRatio(AspectRatio aspect)
{
    switch(aspect)
    {
    case AspectRatio::ASPECT_RATIO_16_9:
    // ...
    default:
            std::cerr << "Undefined aspect ratio enum value!" << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

This works for me exactly as I would expect it to in C#.

### Edit:

Assuming that you are using **at least** C++11, then you are better off declaring an `enum class`:

```cpp
enum class values
{
    AspectRatio_16_9,  // HD video
    AspectRatio_16_2,  // *for testing purposes*
    AspectRatio_4_3,   // standard monitor
    AspectRatio_3_2,   // classic film
    AspectRatio_21_9,  // cinemascope
    AspectRatio_1_1    // quadratic window
};
```

It's a type-safe alternative that does not pollute the enclosing scope. It should also be noted that, in order to prevent name clashing with globally defined macros, `enum class` values should usually not use the `ALL_CAPS` naming convention.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, NOT exactly! if you define any member in the above example before enum class scope, it produces error: #define ASPECT_RATIO_16_9 //ERROR... You must declare enum class before any #include

Comment: @DmitryBabich if I understand what you mean correctly - it would probably be best correcting the error by deleting the `#define` macro bearing the same name and only use the scoped enum.

Comment: Yes. If a symbol is defined globally prior to enum class declaration, it is impossible to use the same symbol within enum class, since it is expanding the definition. You can declare enum class prior to #define statement, but it is not always possible. The best is to follow naming convention: GLOBAL_SYMBOL vs EnumSymbol

Comment: @DmitryBabich yes you are right, and I adjusted my answer to reflect that. It was a while ago that I wrote this, so thank you for reminding me.